# How to update data in .ejs template?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I wish to update data in .ejs template when I write and post a new message, there is my code:

a part of my home.ejs

```
<%
        if(posts){
            for(let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
        %>
        <article class="post">
            <div class="infos">
                <%= posts[i].name.toUpperCase() + ' ' + posts[i].surname; %>
                <%
                if(posts[i].userId === userId){
                %>
                <span class="edit">
                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" onclick="editPost('<%= posts[i].id; %>')"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-trash" onclick="deletePost('<%= posts[i].id; %>')"></i>
                </span>
                <% } %>
            </div>
            <div class="edit" id="post<%= posts[i].id; %>">
                <textarea id="post<%= posts[i].id; %>"></textarea>
                <div class="button b-red white" id="post<%= posts[i].id; %>">Modifier</div>
            </div>
            <p id="post<%= posts[i].id; %>"><%= posts[i].message; %></p>
        </article>
        <% }} %>
```

a part of my app.js

```
fetch.get('https://localhost:3000/api/auth/users')
.then((users) => {

fetch.get('https://localhost:3000/api/posts')
    .then((json) => {

        app.get('/home', function(req, res) {

            const userId = parseInt(req.cookies.userId);
            const posts = json;
            user = users.filter(user => user.id === userId)
            res.render('pages/home', {
                token: req.cookies.token,
                posts: posts,
                userId: userId,
                name: user[0].name,
                surname: user[0].surname
            });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));      
})
```

I've searched for hours on Google for how to update data but I don't understand anything of find anything..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your answer, but the actual problem is that i need to restart my frontend server so that my data is updated in the display of my .ejs rendering